# How to perform action when woocommerce cart cleared by expired session?

Tags: session, woocommerce, cart

I have set up custom session expiration times to be 5 minutes. I am making custom seat information unavailable when a WC product that is a seat is added to cart.

I was able to get the cart to clear when session expire in 5 minutes but I am not able to run an action to make that same seat available back again during cart cleaning process upon session expiration.

The actions "woocommerce_cart_emptied" "woocommerce_cart_item_removed" "woocommerce_remove_cart_item" doesnt seem to be run when the cart is cleared by expired session. Does any of you know how to perform a function when cart clear upon expired session?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following hook `woocommerce_cleanup_sessions`